# Why the coroutine is keep working even if displaying the text is over?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm reading paragraphs from the text field and display each paragraph for a specific amount of time using the variable Line Display Time.

for example Line Display Time in the inspector in the editor is set to 3 so each block paragraph will be display for 3 seconds.

while a text is displaying i'm also starting a mouth coroutine and stop it when it finishes to display the current paragraph text then start the mouth again and stop and so on.

the problem is with the last displaying paragraph text. the time it's displaying is not 3 seconds the last one is show for 1 second maybe less.  and the mouth coroutine is keep working for about more 3 seconds after it finish show all the paragraphs. but the mouth coroutine should stop when the last paragraph finish show.

this is the two lines for the line display time and the mouth animation coroutine:

```
// Wait for the line display time
yield return new WaitForSeconds(lineDisplayTime);

// Stop the mouth animation
mouthController.StopMouthAnimation();
```

I used a breakpoint and the lineDisplayTime at the last paragraph show 3 but the text is not waiting showing it for 3 seconds but for a second or less then when the last paragraph finished show the mouth animation is keep working for more 3 seconds then it's getting to the line and stop:

```
mouthController.StopMouthAnimation();
```

something is wrong with the last paragraph. something with the logic of the code.

```
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections;
using System;

public class CharacterDialogue : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TextMeshProUGUI textMeshPro;
    public float lineDisplayTime;
    public float emptyLineTime;
    public PlayerMouthSpeechController mouthController;
    public GameObject uiSceneText;
    public RectTransform textRectTransform; // Reference to the RectTransform of the TextMeshPro component

    private Coroutine displayCoroutine;
    private string textToDisplay = string.Empty;

    public void StartDialogue()
    {
        textToDisplay = textMeshPro.text;
        StartDialogue(textToDisplay);
    }

    public void StartDialogue(string text)
    {
        // Split the text into lines that fit within the textRectTransform size
        string[] lines = SplitTextToFit(text, textRectTransform.rect.width, textMeshPro);

        if (lines == null || lines.Length == 0)
        {
            Debug.LogWarning("No lines provided for dialogue.");
            return;
        }

        // Stop any ongoing display coroutine
        if (displayCoroutine != null)
        {
            StopCoroutine(displayCoroutine);
        }

        // Enable the UI text
        if (uiSceneText != null)
        {
            uiSceneText.SetActive(true);
        }

        // Start a new coroutine to display the lines one by one
        displayCoroutine = StartCoroutine(DisplayLines(lines));
    }

    private string[] SplitTextToFit(string text, float maxWidth, TextMeshProUGUI textMeshPro)
    {
        List<string> lines = new List<string>();
        StringBuilder currentLine = new StringBuilder();

        string[] words = text.Split(' ');
        float currentLineWidth = 0f;
        bool isFirstWord = true;

        foreach (string word in words)
        {
            float wordWidth = GetWordWidth(word, textMeshPro);

            if (!isFirstWord)
            {
                // Add a space before the word
                wordWidth += GetWordWidth(" ", textMeshPro);
                currentLine.Append(' ');
            }

            if (currentLineWidth + wordWidth <= maxWidth)
            {
                currentLine.Append(word);
                currentLineWidth += wordWidth;
            }
            else
            {
                lines.Add(currentLine.ToString().Trim());
                currentLine.Length = 0;
                currentLineWidth = 0f;
                isFirstWord = true;
            }

            isFirstWord = false;
        }

        if (currentLine.Length > 0)
        {
            lines.Add(currentLine.ToString().Trim());
        }

        return lines.ToArray();
    }

    private float GetWordWidth(string word, TextMeshProUGUI textMeshPro)
    {
        TextMeshProUGUI tempText = Instantiate(textMeshPro);
        tempText.text = word;
        tempText.rectTransform.sizeDelta = new Vector2(0f, textMeshPro.rectTransform.sizeDelta.y); // Match the text height

        return tempText.preferredWidth;
    }

    private IEnumerator DisplayLines(string[] lines)
    {
        // Clear the existing text
        textMeshPro.text = "";

        // Split the input text into paragraphs
        string[] paragraphs = textToDisplay.Split(new[] { "\n\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

        // Iterate through each paragraph and display it for the specified time
        foreach (string paragraph in paragraphs)
        {
            textMeshPro.text = paragraph;

            // Start the mouth animation
            mouthController.StartMouthAnimation(lineDisplayTime);

            // Wait for the line display time
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(lineDisplayTime);

            // Stop the mouth animation
            mouthController.StopMouthAnimation();

            // Wait for the empty line time
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(emptyLineTime);
        }

        // Clear the text after displaying all paragraphs
        textMeshPro.text = "";

        // Deactivate the UI text
        if (uiSceneText != null)
        {
            uiSceneText.SetActive(false);
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the mouth controller script

```
using System.Collections;
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class PlayerMouthSpeechController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TMP_Text[] texts;
    public float duration;
    [Range(0, 100)]
    public float valueRange;

    private bool startTalking = false;
    private SkinnedMeshRenderer bodySkinnedMeshRenderer;

    private Coroutine mouthAnimationCoroutine;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        bodySkinnedMeshRenderer = GetComponent<SkinnedMeshRenderer>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }

    // Lerp between startValue and endValue over 'duration' seconds
    private IEnumerator LerpShape(float startValue, float endValue, float duration)
    {
        float elapsed = 0;
        while (elapsed < duration)
        {
            elapsed += Time.deltaTime;
            float value = Mathf.Lerp(startValue, endValue, elapsed / duration);
            bodySkinnedMeshRenderer.SetBlendShapeWeight(0, value);
            yield return null;
        }
    }

    // Start the mouth animation with a specified time or indefinitely
    public void StartMouthAnimation(float TimeToTalk = 0)
    {
        if (mouthAnimationCoroutine != null)
        {
            StopCoroutine(mouthAnimationCoroutine);
        }

        if (TimeToTalk > 0)
        {
            mouthAnimationCoroutine = StartCoroutine(StartAnimating(TimeToTalk));
        }
        else
        {
            startTalking = true;
            mouthAnimationCoroutine = StartCoroutine(StartAnimating(duration));
        }
    }

    // Stop the mouth animation
    public void StopMouthAnimation()
    {
        if (startTalking)
        {
            startTalking = false;
            if (mouthAnimationCoroutine != null)
            {
                StopCoroutine(mouthAnimationCoroutine);
            }
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator StartAnimating(float TimeToTalk)
    {
        startTalking = true;

        StartCoroutine(TalkingTime(TimeToTalk));

        while (startTalking)
        {
            yield return StartCoroutine(LerpShape(0, valueRange, duration));
            yield return StartCoroutine(LerpShape(valueRange, 0, duration));
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator TalkingTime(float TalkTime)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(TalkTime);

        startTalking = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: youd need to show the mouth controller your character dialogue doesnt seem to be part of the issue other than how you called it  and please [mcve] not the whole darn thing